# How to execute select row(*) in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

In postgres you can return a `row` as a single cell as in the following:

```
select row(date_created,created_By)
from some_table
```

However this does not work when you execute `select row(*)`

Does anybody know how to implement the `row()` function using `asterisk` so if my table changes in the future, I will not have to modify my query?

I am using Postgres version 8.4.1

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you just use `select *`? What is the **real** problem you are trying to solve here? Also: Postgres 8.4 is no longer maintained, you should really plan an upgrade to a supported version as soon as possible (at least use the latest minor version which is 8.4.22)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to prefix the `*` with the table-name or table-alias.

[Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

```
select row(s.*)
from some_table s
```

Comment: Genius! Thank you.